# I need partition scheme advice (MBR) for performance increase

Tags: partitioning, ssd

i partitioned my 500gb SSD for 60(personal)-30(system)-10(free) rule but this is just big picture, i don't know details. I read there have to be swap, var partitions to increase performance. My pc is in his last phase so it hardly breathe. I want to know which scheme i may follow. I am on HDD now.

system:
intel core i5 2300
4gb ram(single)
500gb SSD
Nvidia 220 GC
Ubuntu 22.10 OS
https://imgur.com/xYGrdQX

Comment: I used to recommend 30GB for / (root), but now with snaps, you may need 50GB. Default is 2GB swap files, but many suggest 4GB swap partition. Use gpt partitioning, and if BIOS add a 1MB unformatted bios_grub partition or if UEFI add an ESP - efi system partition FAT32 with boot,esp flags, typically 100MB to 500MB. Partitioning will not improve performance, but ssd will make a big difference. With UEFI much better to use gpt, but not for performance but reliability.

Comment: *"I read there have to be swap, var partitions to increase performance"* - No, this is incorrect. Partitioning won't affect performance, especially on an SSD. SSDs can have any sector read without having to manually seek. It's likely that you're reading outdated advice. It also used to be common to have a separate `/home` partition, but this is less common because it's not as practical as it used to be. The default partitioning (everything on one partition) is best for most people, that's why it's the default.

Comment: You are wasting a lot of space with that 27.95 GiB /efi/boot patition. Even on multiboot systems it's contents will hardly grow any bigger than 500MB, setting it to 1 GB is more than enough. Having a separate /home partition is not really necessary, but can be handy in some use cases. Having a swap partition is a choice, you can also use a swap file in any (or all) existing patitions.